# How to optimize MySQL query for MAX primary key value with one where condition

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a mySQL table with about 30M rows, with an int(10) primary key `id` index (auto-increment) and a few other id columns eg. `modem_id`. modem_id column has a BTREE index with cardinality of about 300.

I am doing a very simple query eg.
`` SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages` WHERE `modem_id`=1234 ``

I would think this should execute very quickly but it is consistently taking 1-2 seconds. Profiling the query in phpMyAdmin tells me that the time is all in the "Sending Data" state which doesn't make sense because the only data returned is one integer value.

How can this be sped up?

Comment: run EXPLAIN your query and see the results, maybe a HINT INDEx helps

Comment: Running EXPLAIN just shows that the query is using the modem_id index, filtering to ~400K rows.

Comment: SOLUTION:  I found that doing a ```SELECT `id` FROM `message_9` WHERE `modem_id`=1234 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1``` runs 100+ times faster! (eg. 10mS). So that resolves my issue, however the question still remains why MAX() is so slow?

Comment: answer and accept the answer but it is a duplicate

Comment: nbk, what's it a duplicate of? Would be nice to know what the issue is with MAX. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ADD INDEX(modem_id, id)
```

In general, the query

```
SELECT MAX(x) FROM t WHERE y = 1234
```

Needs `INDEX(y, x)` -- in that order.

If you have `INDEX(y)` and the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB` and `x` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then `INDEX(y, x)` is the same as `INDEX(y)`.  And your two `SELECTs` will probably run in identical time and have the same `EXPLAINs`.

Without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I can't tell if you have another problem -- When doing `y = 1234` and `y` is `VARCHAR`, the test cannot use an index.  Either change `y` to `INT` or quote the constant: `y = "1234"`.

The speedup of 100+ that you got may have been due to caching.  Run both queries twice.  For further analysis, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` of both queries.

Comment: After adding that index the MAX query is now extremely fast (<1mS) vs. closer to 2 seconds without the index. I already had indexes on each column but it now seems obvious that having an index on both will then let the DB find the MAX just by looking at the index with no need to even look at the table itself. 

BTW the ```SELECT x FROM t WHERE y=1234 ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1``` does in fact also run very fast (~1mS) not due to caching, I tried the query on different tables and with different parameters. And both columns are INT columns.

Comment: @DavidG - Such is called a "covering" index.  And the SELECT in your comment also uses that index to very good effect.  More index discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql